# Tensor Product of an Extension Field and Quotient of a Polynomial Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, tensor-products

Let $F$ be a field, and $E$ be an extension of it. Let $p$ be a polynomial over $F$. We need to show that $$E \otimes_F \frac{F[x]}{(p)} \cong \frac{E[x]}{(p)}.$$

Here is what I thought :
Consider the map $ E \times \frac{F[x]}{(p)} \to \frac{E[x]}{(p)} $ given by $(e, f + (p)) \mapsto ef + (p)$. This map is bilinear, thus by Universal property there exist an $F$-map $\phi:E \otimes_F \frac{F[x]}{(p)} \to \frac{E[x]}{(p)}$ such that $\phi(e \otimes f+ (p)) = ef + (p).$
I think that the map $\phi$ is an isomorphism, but I am not able to think of what the inverse is.

I feel that the above map is a natural bilinear map from $ E \times \frac{F[x]}{(p)} \to \frac{E[x]}{(p)} $, but in the other direction, if I have $g + (p) \in \frac{E[x]}{(p)},$ from $g$, I need to find a polynomial $f \in F[x]$ and an element $e \in E$ such that $g +(p) \mapsto e \otimes f+(p)$ is well defined and an $F$-map. I am not able to figure out any such natural map. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $g=\sum_i a_ix^i$ with $a_i\in E$, then $g+(p)\mapsto \sum_ia_i\otimes (x^i+(p))$ should work. Anyway, I would also consider proving this as follows. We have a short exact sequence
$$0\to F[x]\to F[x]\to F[x]/(p)\to0,$$ where the first map is multiplication by $p$, and the second is the natural projection. $E$ is a flat $F$-module so tensoring with it preserves exactness. Clearly $E\otimes F[x]\simeq E[x]$ so we get
$$0\to E[x]\to E[x]\to E\otimes(F[x]/(p))\to0,$$ with the first map still being multiplication by $p$. But the cokernel of that map is obviously $E[x]/(p)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you. This solves my problem. I did not think that we could send $a_i x^i \mapsto a_i \otimes x^i + (p)$.

Comment: Good. Feel free to post it as an answer yourself for more feedback. I suspect the question may be a duplicate (it is a very natural question), but I gotta commute.